# how to insert current date in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a date field with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP attribute. and I am trying to insert date in the database but the value storing as '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

My code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $sql = "insert into `od_request` (`username`, `amount`, `status`, `date`) values ('$login_session', '$amount', 'Request', 'NOW()')";
    $retval =  mysql_query($sql);
    if($retval) {
        $success= "OD Request Sucessfully Sent!";
    } else {
        $error = "Sorry! Make sure you have entered all the Fields Correctly.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Remove quotes around `NOW()`. `NOW()` is a MySQL function, not a PHP function.

Comment: thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use this request :

```
INSERT INTO `od_request` (`username`, `amount`, `status`, `date`) VALUES('$login_session', '$amount', 'Request', NOW())
```

You don't need to put `'` around `NOW()` because is an `SQL function`

Comment: explain in briefly your answers so people get solution and learn also. thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Syntax to insert date is wrong:**

use `NOW()` not `'NOW()'`

```
$sql = "insert into `od_request` (`username`, `amount`, `status`, `date`) values ('$login_session', '$amount', 'Request', NOW())";
```

Comment: @MahmoodMohammed then accept so that it helps to other users

Answer (score 0):

`date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` is the MySQL datetime format

eg.

```
$sql = "insert into `od_request` (`username`, `amount`, `status`, `date`) values ('$login_session', '$amount', 'Request', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')"
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

```
$sql = "insert into 'od_request' ('username', 'amount', 'status', 'date') values ('$login_session', '$amount', 'Request', NOW())"
```